# Multiple pairwise correlation analysis between all the columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

Here is a dataframe demo.

```
> df
       a1  a2  a3  a4  b1  b2  b3  b4
    1 480 770 601 953 469 750 588 944
    2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    3   3  13   9  12   3  12   9  12
    4   0   2   4   3   0  14   3   2
    5   0   0  11   0   0   0  11   0
    6 165 292 162 313 180 368 116 368
```

I want to perform pairwise correlation analysis among all the columns in this dataframe using R. An output is like the following where xx means the correlation coefficient:

```
     a1  a2  a3  a4  b1  b2  b3  b4
a1    1  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
a2   xx   1  xx  ...
a3
a4
b1
b2
b3
b4
```

Comment: cf package Hmisc function rcorr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just apply the `cor` which can take a data.frame as input

```
cor(df1)
```

-output

```
         a1        a2        a3        a4        b1        b2        b3        b4
a1 1.0000000 0.9994005 0.9965911 0.9998388 0.9992078 0.9901382 0.9878138 0.9989938
a2 0.9994005 1.0000000 0.9932938 0.9987297 0.9999332 0.9942387 0.9820741 0.9999294
a3 0.9965911 0.9932938 1.0000000 0.9978037 0.9925714 0.9754379 0.9972439 0.9919770
a4 0.9998388 0.9987297 0.9978037 1.0000000 0.9983719 0.9876824 0.9902776 0.9981116
b1 0.9992078 0.9999332 0.9925714 0.9983719 1.0000000 0.9948892 0.9808680 0.9999729
b2 0.9901382 0.9942387 0.9754379 0.9876824 0.9948892 1.0000000 0.9564724 0.9953764
b3 0.9878138 0.9820741 0.9972439 0.9902776 0.9808680 0.9564724 1.0000000 0.9799320
b4 0.9989938 0.9999294 0.9919770 0.9981116 0.9999729 0.9953764 0.9799320 1.0000000
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a1 = c(480L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 165L), a2 = c(770L, 
0L, 13L, 2L, 0L, 292L), a3 = c(601L, 0L, 9L, 4L, 11L, 162L), 
    a4 = c(953L, 0L, 12L, 3L, 0L, 313L), b1 = c(469L, 0L, 3L, 
    0L, 0L, 180L), b2 = c(750L, 0L, 12L, 14L, 0L, 368L), b3 = c(588L, 
    0L, 9L, 3L, 11L, 116L), b4 = c(944L, 0L, 12L, 2L, 0L, 368L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"))
```